# Customisation on Connect 4 game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a connect 4 game in python and I was hoping to allow the player to customise the board (be able to choose the size of the board. However when I try to add this in it breaks my code. Is there any way around this? Or will I just have to hard code the board size in?

```
def CreateBoard(r, c, b, n):

  for i in range(1,(r+1)):
    n.append(str(i))
  b.append(n)

  for i in range(c):
    b.append(['*']*(r))
  return(b)


def printBoard(b):
  for lst in b:
    print(" ".join(lst))
  return b


def check(board, n):
  n = []
  for i in range(1,len(board[1])+1):
    if board[1][i-1] == '*':
      n.append(i)
  print(n)

  user = (input('Enter column: '))

  if(user.isdigit() == True):
    user = int(user)
    if (user in n):
      return(user)
  print('Invalid input')
  return check(board, n)

def WinningCon(b, r, u, c):
  'row'
  loop1 = True
  rowCon = ""
  colCon = ""
  for i in range(0,len(b[1])):
    rowCon += b[r][i]
    if('X'*4 in rowCon) or('O'*4 in rowCon):
      return(True)
  for i in range(1,c+1):
    colCon += b[i][u-1]
    if('X'*4 in colCon) or('O'*4 in colCon):
      return(True)

def Diag2(u, r, b, row, column):
  utemp1 = u-1
  utemp2 = u-1
  rtemp1 = r
  rtemp2 = r
  end = ""
  beg = ""
  while(True):
    beg += b[rtemp1][utemp1]
    if(rtemp1 == 1):
      break
    elif(utemp1 == column):
      break
    rtemp1 -= 1
    utemp1 += 1
  while(True):
    if(rtemp2 == row-1):
      break
    elif(utemp2 == 0):
      break
    rtemp2 +=1
    utemp2 -=1
    end += b[rtemp2][utemp2]
  beg = beg[::-1]
  fullstring = beg+end
  if('X'*4 in fullstring) or('O'*4 in fullstring):
    return(True)

def Diag1(u, r, b, row, column):
  utemp1 = u-1
  utemp2 = u-1
  rtemp1 = r
  rtemp2 = r
  end = ""
  beg = ""
  while(True):
    beg += b[rtemp1][utemp1]
    if(rtemp1 == 1):
      break
    elif(utemp1 == 0):
      break
    rtemp1 -= 1
    utemp1 -= 1
  while(True):
    if(rtemp2 == row-1):
      break
    elif(utemp2 == column):
      break
    rtemp2 +=1
    utemp2 +=1
    end += b[rtemp2][utemp2]
  beg = beg[::-1]
  fullstring = beg+end
  if('X'*4 in fullstring) or('O'*4 in fullstring):
    return(True)

def ProcessInput(u, s, b, r):
  rowNum = r-1
  u = u-1
  while(not b[rowNum][u] == '*'):
    rowNum -= 1
  b[rowNum][u] = s
  return(rowNum)

def EndGame(g, b, p):
  printBoard(b)
  print("Congrats %s, you've won!" %p)
  replayGame = input('Would you like to play again? Yes or No?\n').lower()
  if replayGame == 'yes':
    MainGame()
  else:
    g = False
    return(g)

def MainGame():
  row = 7 #input('Enter number of rows')
  column = 6 #input('Enter number of columns')
  board = []
  nums = []
  board = CreateBoard(row, column, board, nums)
  player1 = 'K'#input('Enter name: ')
  player2 = 'A'#input('Enter name: ')
  turn = 1
  GameOn = True
  while(GameOn):
    board = printBoard(board)

    if(not turn%2 == 0):
      print("It's %s's turn" %player1)
      user = check(board, nums)
      rc = ProcessInput(user, "X", board, row)
      if(WinningCon(board, rc , user, column) == True):
        GameOn = EndGame(GameOn, board, player1)
      elif(Diag1(user, rc, board, row, column) == True):
        GameOn = EndGame(GameOn, board, player1)
      elif(Diag2(user, rc, board, row, column) == True):
        GameOn = EndGame(GameOn, board, player1)
    else:
      print("It's %s's turn" %player2)
      user = check(board, nums)
      rc = ProcessInput(user, "O", board, row)
      if(WinningCon(board, rc , user, column) == True):
        GameOn = EndGame(GameOn, board, player2)
      elif(Diag1(user, rc, board, row, column) == True):
        GameOn = EndGame(GameOn, board, player2)
      elif(Diag2(user, rc, board, row, column) == True):
        GameOn = EndGame(GameOn, board, player2)
    turn +=1



MainGame()
```

An example of an error message it throws up:

```
Enter number of columns4
Enter number of rows5
1 2 3 4
* * * *
* * * *
* * * *
* * * *
* * * *
It's K's turn
[1, 2, 3, 4]
Enter column: 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\609380145\Python\Code Dojo\Connect 4\Connect 4 v3.py", line 169, in <module>
    MainGame()
  File "C:\Users\609380145\Python\Code Dojo\Connect 4\Connect 4 v3.py", line 150, in MainGame
    GameOn = EndGame(GameOn, board, player1)
  File "C:\Users\609380145\Python\Code Dojo\Connect 4\Connect 4 v3.py", line 127, in EndGame
    MainGame()
  File "C:\Users\609380145\Python\Code Dojo\Connect 4\Connect 4 v3.py", line 153, in MainGame
    elif(Diag2(user, rc, board, row, column) == True):
  File "C:\Users\609380145\Python\Code Dojo\Connect 4\Connect 4 v3.py", line 66, in Diag2
    beg += b[rtemp1][utemp1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What exactly "breaks your code"? As I can see, the logic is in CreateBoard and it should work more or less, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Basically if I add it in it throws up multiple error messages. As soon as I fix one another is thrown up.

Comment: Could you please give an example of error message and the line number where it breaks?

Comment: rtemp1 = r.   You have an array with length 4 and you're trying to access arr[4]. But indexes are 0..3.

Comment: This is the issue I am facing. I've coded it originally with hard coding the board so it works fine, but then I have issues like this due to the customisation of the board and I am not sure how to get around it

Comment: The easiest way is to ask user to enter numbers not in 1..n_columns, but in range 0..n_columns-1. At least, it should solve the current problem.

Comment: Surely this issue should be fixed with {def Diag1(u, r, b, row, column):
  utemp1 = u-1
  utemp2 = u-1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def CreateBoard(r, c, b, n):

  for i in range(1,(r+1)):
    n.append(str(i))
  b.append(n)

  for i in range(c):
    b.append(['*']*(r))
  return(b)


def printBoard(b):
  for lst in b:
    print(" ".join(lst))
  return b


def check(board, n):
  n = []
  for i in range(1,len(board[1])+1):
    if board[1][i-1] == '*':
      n.append(i)
  print(n)

  user = (input('Enter column: '))

  if(user.isdigit() == True):
    user = int(user)
    if (user in n):
      return(user)
  print('Invalid input')
  return check(board, n)

def WinningCon(b, r, u, c):
  loop1 = True
  rowCon = ""
  colCon = ""
  for i in range(0,len(b[1])):
    rowCon += b[r][i]
    if('X'*4 in rowCon) or('O'*4 in rowCon):
      return(True)
  for i in range(1,c+1):
    colCon += b[i][u-1]
    if('X'*4 in colCon) or('O'*4 in colCon):
      return(True)

def Diag2(u, r, b, column, row):
  utemp1 = u-1
  utemp2 = u-1
  rtemp1 = r
  rtemp2 = r
  end = ""
  beg = ""
  while(True):

    beg += b[rtemp1][utemp1]
    rtemp1 -= 1
    utemp1 += 1
    if(rtemp1 == 1):
      break
    elif(utemp1 >= column - 1):
      break
  while(True):
    end += b[rtemp2][utemp2]
    rtemp2 +=1
    utemp2 -=1
    if(rtemp2 >= row):
      break
    elif(utemp2 == 0):
      break
  beg = beg[::-1]
  fullstring = beg+end
  if('X'*4 in fullstring) or('O'*4 in fullstring):
    return(True)

def Diag1(u, r, b, column, row):
  utemp1 = u-1
  utemp2 = u-1
  rtemp1 = r
  rtemp2 = r
  end = ""
  beg = ""
  while(True):
    beg += b[rtemp1][utemp1]
    rtemp1 -= 1
    utemp1 -= 1
    if(rtemp1 == 1):
      break
    elif(utemp1 == 0):
      break
  while(True):
    print('Row ' + str(rtemp2))
    print('Colum ' +str(utemp2))

    end += b[rtemp2][utemp2]
    rtemp2 +=1
    utemp2 +=1
    if(rtemp2 >= row):
      break
    elif(utemp2 >= column-1):
      break
  beg = beg[::-1]
  fullstring = beg+end
  if('X'*4 in fullstring) or('O'*4 in fullstring):
    return(True)

def ProcessInput(u, s, b, r):
  rowNum = r
  u = u-1
  print('Row: ' + str(rowNum))
  print('Col: ' + str(u))
  while(not b[rowNum][u] == '*'):
    rowNum -= 1
    print('New Row Num: ' + str(rowNum))
  b[rowNum][u] = s
  printBoard(b)
  return(rowNum)

def EndGame(g, b, p):
  printBoard(b)
  print("Congrats %s, you've won!" %p)
  replayGame = input('Would you like to play again? Yes or No?\n').lower()
  if replayGame == 'yes':
    MainGame()
  else:
    g = False
    return(g)

def MainGame():
  column = int(input('Enter number of columns'))
  row = int(input('Enter number of rows'))
  board = []
  nums = []
  board = CreateBoard(column, row, board, nums)
  player1 = 'K'#input('Enter name: ')
  player2 = 'A'#input('Enter name: ')
  turn = 1
  GameOn = True
  while(GameOn):
    board = printBoard(board)
    user = check(board, nums)
    if(turn%2 != 0):
      print("It's %s's turn" %player1)
      rc = ProcessInput(user, "X", board, row)
    else:
      print("It's %s's turn" %player2)
      rc = ProcessInput(user, "O", board, row)

    if(WinningCon(board, rc , user, row) == True):
      GameOn = EndGame(GameOn, board, player1)
    elif(Diag1(user, rc, board, column, row) == True):
      GameOn = EndGame(GameOn, board, player1)
    elif(Diag2(user, rc, board, column, row) == True):
      GameOn = EndGame(GameOn, board, player1)

    turn +=1


MainGame()
```